# URLS in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova

We are creating an PhoneGap App. In the Terms and conditions are dynamically updadted from the database. We have URLS as well in there. Would some one please tell how to open this URL in browser or APP when the user clicks on it.

Many Thanks 
Kiran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open a URL in the default browser, the following code will do the trick:

```
window.open('http://example.com', '_system');
```